# Convertendo JSON para HTML via AJAX em CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Como faço para usar o retorno JSON no HTML? Seguem os códigos.

Função Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?=base_url('pedido/listar');?>",          
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#pedidos').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Controler:

```
public function listar()
{   
    $this->pedido_model->listarPedidos();       
}
```

Model:

```
public function listarPedidos()
{
    $this->db->select('*');    
    $query = $this->db->get('pedidos');

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $pedido){
        $result[] = array('dados' => '<div class="card comandas text-center" href="#exampleModalCenter" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="card-header">
            '.$pedido['cliente'].'
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">'.$pedido['idPedido'].'</h5>
                <p class="card-text badge badge-success">Aberto</p>
            </div>
        </div>');
    }

    echo  json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: O melhor a fazer é retornar o objeto com as informações e usar essas informações no javascript para montar o seu html.... Vou montar um exemplo e colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o `dataType` para `"json"` e depois faça uma iteração com `for...of` montando o html para depois inserir tudo de uma vez no elemento `#pedidos`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?=base_url('pedido/listar');?>",          
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
       var html = '';
       for(var item of data) html += item.dados;
      $('#pedidos').html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigado :D

Answer (score 2):

O **select** do seu model ficaria assim (evitar de consumir banda "internet") com informações que não usa para montar o HTML:

```
$this->db->select('cliente, idPedido');
```

O **foreach** do model você não usaria.

E no ajax você monta o elemento adicionando com um foreach no retorno;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?=base_url('pedido/listar');?>",          
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
      // loop do conteudo da variavel data aqui
      $('#pedidos').append('<div>'+
        '<h2>HTML da lista vai aqui<h2>'+
      '</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Vou fazer aqui pra ver. Obrigado

Comment: So uma dúvida, em js sou meio ruim, como usaria o foreach nele?